# Is there a German equivalent for "Practical English Usage"

Tags: resource

*Practical English Usage* by [Michael Swan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Swan_(writer)) was the book I used when I was learning English. I would like to have a similar book for German, since it contained a lot of common mistakes made by non-native speakers, as well as good explained grammar.

Comment: What is your level in German. It is above intermediate, I would suggest you **Hammer's German Grammar and Usage**. When I learnt German, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Actually, no. I  need a book similar to the one I mentioned. Its concept is to go throughout the most common mistakes, and to explain them. So, a lot of grammar, but moreover, a lot of explanation of language usage.

Comment: The book is from Oxford university press (as the OALD) so I think it's not too localized but a pretty standard book.

Comment: For those who want to know what's in there: http://ielts-house.net/Ebook/Vocabulary/Practical%20English%20usage.pdf

Comment: Very cool book -- I'd also be interested in a version for German for myself when I am advanced enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

Searching for [häufige fehler deutsch fremdsprache](https://www.google.ie/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=h%C3%A4ufige%20fehler%20deutsch%20als%20fremdsprache&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=7K9vWMPZOIHiwQL95ayIDg) surfaced some nice links. They are not books, but a nice start. I find that normally knowing what search terms to enter in Google makes all the difference.

I hope those help.

[PDF](http://knj.vse.cz/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Typische_Fehler_Deutschlernender.pdf)

[Wiki](https://wiki.zum.de/wiki/Fehleranalyse_in_Deutsch_als_Fremdsprache)

Answer (score 1):

As for common mistakes, you might consider getting "1001 Pitfalls in German." It is out of print, but still easy to find. I own the variant for French, which covers topics like confused words, false friends, and other, well, pitfalls.